# How to match a whole string that contains just two and no more than two digits between 0 and 10 in regex?

Tags: regex

This regex does not work for me as selects all groups of two and multiple digits and not the string.

```
abcde9 = match
abcde12 = not matched
abcde12345678 = not matched
```

What I have at the moment is this, it I just can't include the 0 and the 10 as two digits numbers in the regex, can anyone help me?

```
\d{0,10}[1-9]
```

Comment: I guess, "numbers", not "digits".

Comment: Your question is totally unclear. I have no idea what you want to do here.

Comment: I think you want: `[a-z]+(?:[0-9]|10)`

Comment: Sounds like you are contradicting yourself. You said *contains just two digits* and at the same time *between 0 and 10*. Do you mean that numbers have to start with a zero? Aka `01`, `02`... If that is the case, your first example shouldn't be matched. If that was not the case, why didn't you just ask for a number between 0 and 10?

Comment: What RegEx engine are you using? This is an important piece of info that you've missed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match any string containing exactly one integer from 0 to 10 then use

```
^\D*(\d|10)\D*$
```

which means "any non-digit content followed by either a single digit or the number 10 and then followed by any non-digit content"

try it at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eR6nL8/2)

Comment: This is the most clear answer and I managed to change it further.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you looking for:

```
/(0[1-9])$/
```

You can test that regex to make sure it fits your needs:
https://regex101.com/r/hX6lB7/3

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for

```
^\D*(?:[0-9]|10)(?:\D+(?:[0-9]|10))?\D*$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nN8wD8/2)

This will match a whole string that contains 1 or 2 *whole integer numbers* from 0 to 10, and no other digits.

The regex breakdown:

- `^` - start of string
- `\D*` - 0 or more characters other than digit
- `(?:[0-9]|10)` - numbers from 0 to 10
- `(?:\D+(?:[0-9]|10))?` - 1 or 0 occurrence of

  - `\D+` - 1 or more characters other than digit
  - `(?:[0-9]|10)` - numbers from 0 to 10
- `\D*` - 0 or more characters other than digit
- `$` - end of string